# Custom villager trades with potions

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I am making an RPG-style map and as such I needed some custom potions. I tried to make a Wine Merchant that sells a custom potion but when it spawns, it only sells a non-craftble potion. What can I do? My version in 1.16 and I only find old tutorials

Command:

```
summon villager 1442 70 575 {VillagerData:{profession:fletcher,level:2,type:plains},Rotation:[180f,0f],CustomName:"\"Wine Merchant\"",Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:emerald,Count:7},sell:{id:potion,Count:1,tag:{ potion:{CustomPotionColor:16386209,display:{Name:'[{"text":"Cheap Heartland Wine","italic":false}]'},CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:22,Duration:500},{Id:15,Duration:500},{Id:5,Duration:1000}]}}},rewardExp:0b,maxUses:9999999}
```

Comment: I know how to spawn villagers like this. What are the exact things you want it to have? (Profession, Level, Buyables etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I used https://mcstacker.net/ to generate this command:

```
/summon villager 1442 70 575 {Rotation:[180F,0F],CustomName:'{"text":"Wine Merchant"}',VillagerData:{level:2,profession:"minecraft:fletcher",type:"minecraft:plains"},Offers:{Recipes:[{rewardExp:0b,maxUses:2147483647,buy:{id:"minecraft:emerald",Count:7b},sell:{id:"minecraft:potion",Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:'{"text":"Cheap Heartland Wine","italic":false}'},CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:5b,Amplifier:0b,Duration:1000},{Id:15b,Amplifier:0b,Duration:500},{Id:22b,Amplifier:0b,Duration:500}],CustomPotionColor:16386209}}}]}}
```

Comment: What did you change that makes it work?

Comment: I tried to import OP's command, but there seemed to be an error with the command. So, I just recreated it by hand.

Comment: *Give a man a fish, he'll eat for a day. Teach a man to fish, he'll learn for a lifetime.* It would be better of course to explain the error that OP's command has. A question of this type, it's pretty much expected of answers to explain the error, or at least show what they changed to correct the command.

Comment: The issue is, I don't know why OP's command didn't work either...

Comment: Wow thanks a bunch, it worked! It's ok if you don't know what the problem is, I'll see if using this generator helps me in the future. My thanks! Of course I'd still be interested in the error, why it exists at all, it seems to be the location of the custom color in the command that's different, but no matter, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the Custom Villager Shops datapack under utilites [here](https://vanillatweaks.net/picker/datapacks/), it can be used to configure these more easily. Sneak near the villagers to edit their trades.